# gtkmm and FileChooserButton can't get file name

Tags: c++, gtk3, gtkmm3

this is my code, I try get file_name after choose file with widget `FileChooserButton`

```
Gtk::FileChooserButton *chooserButton = nullptr;
std::string idChooserButton = commonArray[b]["id"];
builder->get_widget(idChooserButton, chooserButton);
Php::call("var_dump",chooserButton);
if (strcmp(commonArray[b]["action"], "click") == 0) {
    Php::Value callback = commonArray[b]["callback"];
    chooserButton->signal_selection_changed().connect(
            sigc::bind<Php::Value,Php::Value>(
                    sigc::mem_fun(*this, &ParserGtk::callbacks),
                    callback,
                    chooserButton->get_filename()
            )
    );
}
```

I call functino `get_filename` but `get_filename` return empty string "";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Signals and `sigc::bind` pass values computed at connection time. So when you do

```
chooserButton->get_filename()
```

This will return an empty string, the `Gtk::FileChooserButton` having not been displayed or used at that point.

You will need to call `chooserButton->get_filename()` in your call-back function to get the current value.